# What statement is needed to hear

Tags: countability

[image: 1 triangle consists of 16 triangles]

To hear someone describe it as '16 triangles,' from '1 triangle,' what should I say? I guess, 'how many triangles are there more exactly or more specifically?'

Comment: Hello, are you trying to define a question for your answer? Usually, the image you have shown above is called a “shape”. So may be, you can simply phrase your question as “How many triangles do you count in the given shape?”

Comment: 'How many smallest subdivisions of the triangle do you count in the given shape?'

Comment: “How many smallest triangular subdivisions do you count in the given shape?” would be more apt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying there are 16 triangles in that image, you're only talking about the small ones, right? Not, for example, the four in the bottom left corner that make up a larger triangle?

The reason I ask is there's a common puzzle where you show someone an image like this, and ask them "how many triangles are in this image?" The "trick" is that there are triangles made up of groups of smaller triangles - you can draw more than 16 by following some of the lines.

If you definitely just want to talk about the smallest shapes, you might want to say something like "this triangle has been divided into a number of smaller triangles - how many are there?" So you're focusing on the subdivision, the way it has been cut up, not how many triangles you can make from the pieces.

Here are some words you might want to use that focus on that:

- smallest
- individual
- pieces
- parts
- tiles
- tessellation
- division
- subdivision (I feel like this is a better technical term, it's common in 3D modelling software where you divide triangles into smaller ones)

Comment: Wow, 'subdivision,' good word.